# Call java class defined in jar from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, loadrunner

I have jar file with following code:

MyClass.jar

```
package com.sample;
public class MyClass {
    public static String getName() {
        return "Hii";
    }
}
```

I want to load MyClass.jar in javascript and call getName method.
I've tried following code

```
var cl = new Packages.java.net.URLClassLoader(
        [new Packages.java.net.URL('C:\\tmp\\MyClass.jar')]);
var aClass = Packages.java.lang.Class.forName("MyClass", true, cl);
var aStaticMethod = aClass.getMethod("getName", []);
var greeting = aStaticMethod.invoke(null, []);
```

When I ran the above code I'm getting error "Packages is not defined".

Actually I'm running the above Javascript code in Loadrunner Web Http/html protocol script.

I kept the jar file in Loadrunner bin folder and tried below code.

```java
function myfun() {
    var myvariable = Packages.com.sample;    
    var foo = new myvariable.MyClass();    
    return foo.getName();
}
```

I'm getting same error "Packages is not defined"

Kindly suggest.

Comment: This is not the correct duplicate referenced...

What happens if you remove the "Packages." in your code?

Comment: @SirFartALot if I remove Packages..it is saying java is not define..

Comment: @Ghostcat I cheked the proposed solution...I need to implement the solution in loadrunner...could not understand how to put the jar in the loadrunner classpath

Comment: Then please add some more details there, including that you researched that DUP question, and explain how it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`lr.loadLibrary()` function will be used to import external js to the script but not sure will it import jar files as well. Just give it a try, If not try with JAVA over HTTP protocol- This will definitely help with your requirements.